# ReferenceError: FileReader is not defined in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying out the new functions of Next.js 13 with the `/app` folder, but in a simple client-side component that handles an input form, I am trying to use `FileReader` but receive an error when browsing.

This is the summary of the code:

```js
"use client";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import useStore from "../app/store";

export default function FileUploader() {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);
  const router = useRouter();
  const addFile = useStore((state) => state.addFile);

  const fileReader = new FileReader();

  const onFileSelect = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setFiles(event.target.files);
    console.log(event.target.files);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (files[0] == null) return;
    let FileToString = fileReader.readAsText(files[0]); // get error at this line
    addFile(FileToString);

    router.push("/file/" + filename);
  }, [files]);

  return (
    <input
      id="dropzone-file"
      type="file"
      className="fileInput"
      onChange={onFileSelect}
    />
  );
}
```

Error:

```
wait  - compiling...
event - compiled client and server successfully in 3.4s (758 modules)
ReferenceError: FileReader is not defined
    at FileUploader (webpack-internal:///(sc_client)/./components/FileUploader.js:27:24)
    ...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like accessing `window`, any browser-specific code in Next.js needs to run on the client. If you want to use `FileReader`, which is part of the browser API, add it to your `useEffect`, like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fileReader = new FileReader();
  // ...
}, [files]);
```

This way, Next.js won't look for the definition of a `FileReader` while rendering your component on the server. [Yes, even client components render first on the server, and get hydrated on the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76301770/15288641).