# Getting ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined even after adding "use client"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have a simple `app/components/organisms/Cookies.tsx` modal window component that I import into `app/page.tsx`. I have added the `'use client'` directive at the top of the component, but for some reason, I keep getting:

> ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined

[image]

Code of my `Cookies.tsx`:

```
'use client';
import { useState } from 'react';

const Cookies = () => {
  const localStorageCookies = localStorage.getItem('cookies-accepted');
  const [cookiesAccepted, setCookiesStatus] = useState<boolean>(!!localStorageCookies);

  const acceptCookies = () => {
    localStorage.setItem('cookies-accepted', 'true');
    setCookiesStatus(true);
  }
  
  return (
    <>
      {!cookiesAccepted && (
        <section className="fixed max-w-md p-4 mx-auto bg-white border border-gray-200 left-12 bottom-16  rounded-2xl z-20">
          <h2 className="font-semibold text-gray-800 "> Cookie Notice</h2>

          <p className="mt-4 text-sm text-gray-600">
            We use cookies to ensure that we give you the best experience on our
            website.{' '}
            <a href="#" className="text-blue-500 hover:underline">
              Read cookies policies
            </a>
            .{' '}
          </p>

          <div className="flex items-center justify-between mt-4 gap-x-4 shrink-0">
            <button className="text-xs text-gray-800 underline transition-colors duration-300 hover:text-gray-600 focus:outline-none">
              Manage your preferences
            </button>

            <button
              className=" text-xs bg-gray-900 font-medium rounded-lg hover:bg-gray-700 text-white px-4 py-2.5 duration-300 transition-colors focus:outline-none"
              onClick={acceptCookies}
            >
              Accept
            </button>
          </div>
        </section>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default Cookies;
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried to put `Cookies.tsx` outside of `app` folder but it didn't help.

I'm using version Next.js version `13.4.1`.

Comment: Keep in mind that a component that uses the `'use client'` directive still gets server-side rendered (that's what's causing the error). Any logic that accesses Web APIs (like `localStorage`) needs to be done inside a `useEffect`.

Comment: @juliomalves is right. If you want a link to the doc about this subject and a safe implementation of your code, check out the below answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you can read on [rendering](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering), actually, both Server and Client components render first on the server, and get sent as HTML to the browser (you can see the generated HTML file in the network tab of the browser). Here is a [quote](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components#how-are-client-components-rendered) from the doc:

> To optimize the initial page load, Next.js will use React's APIs to render a static HTML preview on the server for both Client and Server Components. This means, when the user first visits your application, they will see the content of the page immediately, without having to wait for the client to download, parse, and execute the Client Component JavaScript bundle.

The difference between the two is that when you add `"use client"`, it means this component includes client interactivities: so Next.js should send the JavaScript needed (such as event handlers, effects, etc) and attach it to the previously displayed-as-plain-HTML component.

So anything that's browser specific, such as `localStorage`, should not be called in a client component body, but only inside `useEffect`, event handlers...

This should work in your case:

```typescript
"use client";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Cookies = () => {
  const [cookiesAccepted, setCookiesStatus] = useState<boolean | null>(null);

  const acceptCookies = () => {
    localStorage.setItem("cookies-accepted", "true");
    setCookiesStatus(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const localStorageCookies = localStorage.getItem("cookies-accepted");
    setCookiesStatus(!!localStorageCookies);
  }, []);

  if (cookiesAccepted === null || cookiesAccepted) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <section className="fixed max-w-md p-4 mx-auto bg-white border border-gray-200 left-12 bottom-16  rounded-2xl z-20">
      <h2 className="font-semibold text-gray-800 "> Cookie Notice</h2>

      <p className="mt-4 text-sm text-gray-600">
        We use cookies to ensure that we give you the best experience on our website.{" "}
        <a href="#" className="text-blue-500 hover:underline">
          Read cookies policies
        </a>
        .{" "}
      </p>

      <div className="flex items-center justify-between mt-4 gap-x-4 shrink-0">
        <button className="text-xs text-gray-800 underline transition-colors duration-300 hover:text-gray-600 focus:outline-none">
          Manage your preferences
        </button>

        <button
          className=" text-xs bg-gray-900 font-medium rounded-lg hover:bg-gray-700 text-white px-4 py-2.5 duration-300 transition-colors focus:outline-none"
          onClick={acceptCookies}
        >
          Accept
        </button>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Cookies;
```

And do not attempt the `typeof window !== "undefined"` hack as most likely, you would get a [hydration error](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error).

Comment: This is exactly why they should've called them Interactive Components instead of Client Components. When I hear `Client Components`, I intuitively think that they are supposed to only exist on the client, even though now I know that's not true.