# jsVectorMap in Next.js and " Element is not defined" in client component

Tags: next.js

I tried to use `jsvectormap` in my new Next.Js app. This is the component that is causing the error "ReferenceError: Element is not defined" during production development, as well as it is shown in the terminal during development (but the app works when `npm run dev` is run).

```
'use client';

// @ts-ignore
import jsVectorMap from "jsvectormap";
import "jsvectormap/dist/maps/world.js";
import "./WorldMap.css"
import {useEffect} from "react";


export default function WorldMap() {

    useEffect(() => {
        new jsVectorMap({
            selector: "#map",
            map: 'world',
           
        });
    }, [])
    return (
        <div className='bg-gray-100 h-[500px]'>
            <div  id={'map'}></div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I thought `use client` would throw away any issues regarding browser elements, but it seems it's not working. I tried to use `dynamic` but it returns React component, which is not usable in that case.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jsVectorMap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsvectormap) doesn't seem to be Next.js and server-side rendering friendly. [And yes, even a client component first renders on the server with Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76300847/getting-referenceerror-localstorage-is-not-defined-even-after-adding-use-clien). The library seems to execute browser-specific code on import.

You could fix your issue by [lazy loading](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/lazy-loading) the map, by moving it to its own file:

```js
// app/page.js

import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const WorldMap = dynamic(() => import("./WorldMap"), {
  ssr: false,
});

export default function Page() {
  return <WorldMap />;
}
```

```js
// app/WorldMap.js

"use client";

// @ts-ignore
import jsVectorMap from "jsvectormap";
import "jsvectormap/dist/maps/world.js";
import "./WorldMap.css";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function WorldMap() {
  useEffect(() => {
    new jsVectorMap({
      selector: "#map",
      map: "world",
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="bg-gray-100 h-[500px]">
      <div id={"map"}></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```