# Passing callback from server component to client component in Next.js

Tags: next.js

I am stuck at a point where I am creating a custom button component, marking it as a client component, and then I am passing its `onClick` callback from a server-side component, and it's giving me this error:

```
 error Error: Event handlers cannot be passed to Client Component props.
  <button onClick={function} className=... children=...>
                  ^^^^^^^^^^
If you need interactivity, consider converting part of this to a Client Component.
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
digest: "280571554"
```

This is my `WelcomeComponent.tsx` file:

```
import { faPizzaSlice } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { Brand, Button } from "@/components/Common";
import Image from "next/image";

const WelcomeComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div className="border flex items-center justify-center flex-wrap space-x-10 py-10">
      <div className="font-semibold flex flex-col">
        <div className="mr-3 flex items-center text-3xl">
          <span className="mr-2">Welcome to</span>
          <Brand size="large" />
        </div>
        <h2 className="text-2xl">We Serve you with happiness.</h2>
        <Button
          text="Order Now"
          icon={<FontAwesomeIcon className="w-6" icon={faPizzaSlice} />}
          onClick={() => {
            console.log("c");
          }}
        />
      </div>
      <Image
        className="w-auto h-auto"
        height={0}
        width={300}
        src="/man.jpg"
        priority
        alt=""
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default WelcomeComponent;
```

And this is my `Button.tsx` file:

```
interface Props {
  text: string;
  icon: React.JSX.Element;
  onClick: () => void;
}

const Button = ({ text, icon, onClick }: Props) => {

  return (
    <button
      onClick={onClick}
      className="shadow-lg my-5 flex items-center justify-center text-white bg-orange-400 hover:bg-orange-500 rounded-md p-3 w-40 space-x-2"
    >
      <span className="text-md">{text}</span>
      {icon}
    </button>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

As you can see I want to pass the `onClick` callback to the `Button` component which I am calling in the `WelcomeComponent.tsx`.

I'm using Next.js `v13.4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because [Server Components](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#server-components) gets compiled to HTML and sent to the browser with no additional JavaScript, that click handler in your case. And this makes it so you can only pass non-function values from a server component to a client one.

The component that calls `Button` should be a client one, with `"use client"` at the top, as you need to pass a function from there, and it's okay, as Lee Robinson from Vercel [says](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/43704#issuecomment-1577133328):

> Client Components aren't a de-opt, nor a cop-out. You can think of Server Components as an additive to the existing model. I understand the sentiment of wanting to use Server Components for lots of things (not bad!) but it's also totally okay to use Client Components for certain things.

```
"use client"; // Need to send a JavaScript function to the browser 

import { faPizzaSlice } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { Brand, Button } from "@/components/Common";
import Image from "next/image";

const WelcomeComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div className="border flex items-center justify-center flex-wrap space-x-10 py-10">
      <div className="font-semibold flex flex-col">
        <div className="mr-3 flex items-center text-3xl">
          <span className="mr-2">Welcome to</span>
          <Brand size="large" />
        </div>
        <h2 className="text-2xl">We Serve you with happiness.</h2>
        <Button
          text="Order Now"
          icon={<FontAwesomeIcon className="w-6" icon={faPizzaSlice} />}
          onClick={() => {
            console.log("c");
          }}
        />
      </div>
      <Image
        className="w-auto h-auto"
        height={0}
        width={300}
        src="/man.jpg"
        priority
        alt=""
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

[Also, even a client component first renders on the server with Next.js to improve initial load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76300847/getting-referenceerror-localstorage-is-not-defined-even-after-adding-use-clien). And if you are worrying SEO, checkout this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76900732/15288641).