# Nextjs how to re-get data in server component when triggered from client component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jotai

I have two parallel routes, one being a server component that displays a list of things and the other being a client component that adds a thing to the list. The server component does a sql (mysql2) query to get the list and similarly, the client component does a sql query to add to the list.

I am wondering how can I make the server component's list update after the client component adds to it. I'd like to know how to update the server component's list **without doing another db query**, as the query from the client component returns the new thing that was added to the list; I just want to use that result to update the server component's list.

I am open to using a state management library such as jotai, but I am not sure how this works within server components as hooks can't be used; I want to avoid prop drilling.

Comment: Chekcout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75124513/update-server-component-after-data-has-been-changed-by-client-component-in-next.

Comment: That answer does an additional DB query to get the data again, which I want to avoid because I already have the new list item returned from the insert. Is there no way to avoid an additional query?

Comment: Non you cannot. I have posted a more elaborated answer with some links. I hope it's helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of [Server Components](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components) like any templating engine such as [Blade](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade), [EJS](https://ejs.co), and [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com). They get transformed to plain HTML files when there is a request and sent to the browser. Like the other templating engines, to update them, you need to [refresh the page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75127011/15288641), hence in your case, call the DB.

If you need a different behavior (such as updating the component on the client), you should be using a [client component](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components), aka the `"use client"`. And you shouldn't try to fight this idea, as Lee Robinson from Vercel [says](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/43704#issuecomment-1577133328):

> Client Components aren't a de-opt, nor a cop-out. You can think of Server Components as an additive to the existing model. I understand the sentiment of wanting to use Server Components for lots of things (not bad!) but it's also totally okay to use Client Components for certain things.

[Also, even a client component first renders on the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76900438/seo-performance-with-next-js-app-router-server-component-or-client-components) with Next.js to improve the page initial load.

Comment: It seems to me that I would need to make basically every component a client component then because I want to update the "state" from a client component (and incorporate optimistic updates). Is this the idea?

Comment: Yeah, this is the philosophy. I need client interactivity, I use a client component.

Answer (score 0):

[From the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/parallel-routes):

> Parallel Routes allows you to simultaneously or conditionally render
> one or more pages within the same layout. They are useful for highly
> dynamic sections of an app, such as dashboards and feeds on social
> sites.

If I understand your use case correct, I would simplify the structure and avoid parallel routes.

**`/things-list/page.tsx` (React Server Component)**

RSC which queries the datastore and renders the result `things-list`

**`/things-list/interactive-rcc.tsx` (React Client Component)**

This RCC receives data (`things-list`) from the RSC (props) and can fetch additional data.

Or let the RSC query this additional data if possible and receive it in `props`

Initiate datastore mutation with [Server Actions](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions-and-mutations). In forms or event handlers.

**`/things-list/server-actions.tsx` (React Server Component)**

RSC which mutates the datastore triggerd on form inputs or event handlers of a React Client Component.

In general, it is preferable to stick with simple, recommended patterns. But you know better. Perhaps I misunderstand your demand.

Comment: I do want parallel routes because I want a modal. Next's modal example uses parallel routes and it is nice to not have to keep track of modal open/close state in a client component this way

Comment: I see. Here they show how RSC, RCC and Server Actions play nicely together. I think, this will work too with parallel routes. https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app/mutating-data#creating-an-invoice