# window or localStorage is not defined in "use client" component

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am trying to create a wrapper function to use in every dashboard component.

```
"use client";

const UserWrapper = ({ children }) => {
  const user = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("ysg_u"));

  return (
    <div>
      {user?.token ? (
        children
      ) : (
        <div className="min-h-screen flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
          <TbFaceIdError className=" w-8 h-8 mb-2" />
          <p className="font-headliner text-3xl tracking-wider">ACCESS DENIED</p>
          <p className="text-xl -mt-2 font-teko">
            Please{" "}
            <Link href={"/login"} className="text-orange-700 underline">
              Login
            </Link>{" "}
            First
          </p>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserWrapper;
```

Removed all the imports for long code. Error showing but working. Failing to complete the build command in Vercel:

```
 event compiled client and server successfully in 729 ms (2087 modules)
- error src/components/Wrapper/user.wrapper.js (11:26) @ window
- error ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at UserWrapper (./src/components/Wrapper/user.wrapper.js:22:29)
   9 | 
  10 | const UserWrapper = ({ children }) => {
> 11 |   const user = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("ysg_u"));
     |                          ^
  12 | 
  13 |   //   useEffect(() => {
  14 |   //     if (!user?.admin) {
- warn The server is running out of memory, restarting to free up memory.
- wait compiling...
- event compiled client and server successfully in 468 ms (2087 modules)
```

I am using the `use client` tag but I don't know why it is showing the same either `window` or `localStorage` is not defined.

It will work if I use it with the `useEffect` and `useState` hook solution. But the problem is for every route change screen will flash the screen of no user for a second and then the page will load. Because initially, `useState` takes few ms to load the `localStorage` to state.

Any solution on how to solve this properly? I'm using Next.js 13.

Thank you ❤️

Comment: Please don't [post pictures of your errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11968910), instead copy and paste the errors into a code block using backticks (`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Even a client component first renders on the server with Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76300847/getting-referenceerror-localstorage-is-not-defined-even-after-adding-use-clien), so anything that's browser specific, such as `localStorage`, should not be called in a client component body, but only inside `useEffect`, event handlers...

Now about the page flicker you talked about, this should work:

```js
"use client";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const UserWrapper = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    setUser(() => {
      try {
        return JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("ysg_u"));
      } catch (error) {
        return null;
      }
    });
  }, []);

  // You can return a loading state if you want:
  if (user === undefined) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {user?.token ? (
        children
      ) : (
        <div className="min-h-screen flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
          <TbFaceIdError className=" w-8 h-8 mb-2" />
          <p className="font-headliner text-3xl tracking-wider">ACCESS DENIED</p>
          <p className="text-xl -mt-2 font-teko">
            Please{" "}
            <Link href={"/login"} className="text-orange-700 underline">
              Login
            </Link>{" "}
            First
          </p>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserWrapper;
```

And do not attempt the `window !== "undefined"` hack as most likely, you would get a hydration error.