# NextJS 13, Use Client not working only using Server Side Rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I'm trying to create client rendered components such as a navbar with a use effect to detect scroll. So to do that I have the documented

`"use client";`

at the top of the page. Issue is when the code compiles and runs it still seems to be compiled as a server side rendered component. As the use effect doesn't seem to run and If I put a console log into the component it logs it to the server log rather than client.

the following is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "starter",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.48.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^13.4.19",
    "next": "^13.4.19",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  }
}
```

The next is another example in a different project on another machine and it doesn't seem to work either. It is a simple ThemeContext that will only run seemingly as server side. as it either detects the window type and if I delete the if statement then it flags localStorage as not existing which I believe means its rendering on client side.

```
"use client";

import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const ThemeContext = createContext();

const getFromLocalStorage = () => {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    const value = localStorage.getItem("theme");
    return value || "light";
  }
};

export const ThemeContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(() => {
    return getFromLocalStorage();
  });

  const toggle = () => {
    setTheme(theme === "light" ? "dark" : "light");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("theme", theme);
  }, [theme]);

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme, toggle }}>
      {children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

I then wrap it the application with the context same as I would in react and when I try to access it in a client rendered component it seems to only console log to server.

```
'use client';

import Image from "next/image";
import styles from "./themeToggle.module.css";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { ThemeContext } from "@/context/ThemeContext";

const ThemeToggle = () => {
  const { toggle, theme } = useContext(ThemeContext);

  console.log(theme)

  return (
    <div
      className={styles.container}
      onClick={toggle}
      style={
        theme === "dark" ? { backgroundColor: "white" } : { backgroundColor: "#0f172a" }
      }
    >
      <Image src="/moon.png" alt="" width={14} height={14} />
      <div
        className={styles.ball}
        style={
          theme === "dark"
            ? { left: 1, background: "#0f172a" }
            : { right: 1, background: "white" }
        }
      ></div>
      <Image src="/sun.png" alt="" width={14} height={14} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ThemeToggle;
```

I have tried it on 2 separate machines and tried creating 2 different projects with NextJS 13 and have encountered the same issue on both.

I read somewhere it may be an issue with WSL and I can confirm I'm on the most recent version of WSL.

I have tried completely deleting node modules and fresh installing. The fact this is happening to me on 2 machines on 2 different projects does leave me to believe it is an error on my side but I cannot work it out.

**Edit**
For context the second project I tried following this tutorial and it’s this that contains these 2 examples I’ve posted. [video](https://youtu.be/DpYE5zPDRVQ?si=mqbtLrv5aoZ8Kghj)

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76300847/getting-referenceerror-localstorage-is-not-defined-even-after-adding-use-clien.

Comment: That’s the thing it won’t even trigger a use effect when rendering. I tried creating a header with event listener on scroll with useEffecf with use client and it wouldn’t even trigger once.

Comment: @JackDuffy updating Node fixed this issue for me.