# Getting `ReferenceError: document is not defined` while deploying Next.js project in Vercel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-quill

I am working on a Next JS project and I have deployed it to Vercel and at first it was working totally fine and that's why I did'nt check the website status for long time and just developing it locally and pushing into GitHub. Now suddenly I am checked it and getting this error.

```js
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at t.exports.r.INSERT (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/dashboard/create/page.js:1:160188)
    at r (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/dashboard/create/page.js:1:27485)
    at t.exports.Object.defineProperty.value (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/dashboard/create/page.js:1:43298)
    at r (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/dashboard/create/page.js:1:27485)
    at t.exports.Object.defineProperty.value (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/dashboard/create/page.js:1:125932)
    at r (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/dashboard/create/page.js:1:27485)
    at t.exports.Object.defineProperty.value (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/dashboard/create/page.js:1:196459)
    at r (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/dashboard/create/page.js:1:27485)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/dashboard/create/page.js:1:239478)
    at r (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/dashboard/create/page.js:1:27485)
Error occurred prerendering page "/dashboard/create". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at t.exports.r.INSERT (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/dashboard/create/page.js:1:160188)
    at r (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/dashboard/create/page.js:1:27485)
    at t.exports.Object.defineProperty.value (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/dashboard/create/page.js:1:43298)
    at r (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/dashboard/create/page.js:1:27485)
    at t.exports.Object.defineProperty.value (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/dashboard/create/page.js:1:125932)
    at r (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/dashboard/create/page.js:1:27485)
    at t.exports.Object.defineProperty.value (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/dashboard/create/page.js:1:196459)
    at r (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/dashboard/create/page.js:1:27485)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/dashboard/create/page.js:1:239478)
    at r (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/dashboard/create/page.js:1:27485)
```

I try to read this and found that something is wrong into this directory

```
/app/dashboard/page.js
```

i am sure that i did'nt use the doucment on that perticular file. but i use the doucment in the Navbar.jsx file. here is the code

```js
const [toggle_icon, set_toggle_icon] = useState(faBarsStaggered);

useEffect(() => {
        if (toggle_icon == faBarsStaggered) {
            menuRef.current.style.left = "-110%"
            document.body.style.overflowY = 'scroll'
        } else {
            menuRef.current.style.left = "0"
            document.body.style.overflowY = 'hidden'
        }
    }, [toggle_icon])
```

i use that code to set the body overflow-y hidden when the menu is opend.
now i don't know what is causing the error. please help me with that.
if you need anything else to know more about the error please let me know.

**Edit**

I remove all the code that can cause the error (localstorage, window, document) and add the
`use client`
to all componenet that can cause the error. I also tried to delete all cache in vercel. And re-deploy it to vercel and i gets the same error.

Now I remove the whole folder
`/app/dashboard/create`
and deploy it and now it works.

this is the code i have on that file `/app/dashboard/create/page.jsx`

```js
'use client'

// pages/create-post.js
import React from 'react';
import AdminForm from '@/components/admin/AdminForm';

export default function CreatePostPage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Create a New Post</h1>
      <AdminForm />
    </div>
  );
};
```

and the AdminForm `@/components/admin/AdminForm` (I use this in `/app/dashboard/create/page.jsx` file) file contains this code

```js
'use client'

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactQuill from 'react-quill';
import 'react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css';

export default function AdminForm() {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
  const [content, setContent] = useState('');

  // Handle title change
  const handleTitleChange = (e) => {
    setTitle(e.target.value);
  };

  // Handle content change
  const handleContentChange = (value) => {
    setContent(value);
  };

  // Handle form submission
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // You can perform actions like saving the title and content to the database here
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Title input field */}
      <input
        type="text"
        value={title}
        onChange={handleTitleChange}
        placeholder="Enter title"
      />

      {/* Text editor for content */}
      <ReactQuill
        theme="snow"
        value={content}
        onChange={handleContentChange}
        placeholder="Enter content"
      />

      {/* Submit button */}
      <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ReactQuill` in `AdminForm` seems to call browser specific APIs at import. And knowing that [even client components first render on the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76300847/getting-referenceerror-localstorage-is-not-defined-even-after-adding-use-clien), you are getting that error at build time.

A solution is to import the `AdminForm` with the [`dynamic`](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/lazy-loading#nextdynamic) function of Next.js, like so:

```js
// pages/create-post.js

const AdminForm = dynamic(() => import("./AdminForm"), {
  ssr: false,
});

export default function CreatePostPage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Create a New Post</h1>
      <AdminForm />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score -1):

In nextJs some time client component is act as server component at initial point. you can check document is ready or not before accessing it.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof document !== "undefined") {
        if (toggle_icon === faBarsStaggered) {
            menuRef.current.style.left = "-110%";
            document.body.style.overflowY = "scroll";
        } else {
            menuRef.current.style.left = "0";
            document.body.style.overflowY = "hidden";
        }
    }
}, [toggle_icon]);
```

Comment: "In nextJs some time client component is act as server component at initial point. you can check document is ready or not before accessing it" is not accurate. SSR is not a Server Component.

Comment: Thanks mate but i tried it also.